# Como verificar se o Termo está contido em String no PHP?

Tags: php, string, variáveis

Preciso verificar se uma determinada `tag` está dentro da `string`. Eu recebo essa string do banco de dados que vem em forma de `tags` separadas por vírgula sem espaços conforme está abaixo:

**String**

```
canais,proteses,implantes
```

**Termo**

```
proteses
```

Como verificar com PHP se `Termo` está contido dentro de `String`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma com expressão regular em PHP:

```
<?php

$tags = 'canais,proteses,implantes';
$termo = 'proteses';

$pattern = '/' . $termo . '/';//Padrão a ser encontrado na string $tags
if (preg_match($pattern, $tags)) {
  echo 'Tag encontrada';
} else {
  echo 'Tag não encontrada';
}
```

Ou também usando as funções explode e in_array da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$tags = 'canais,proteses,implantes';
$tagsArray = explode(',', $tags);
$termo = 'proteses';

if (in_array($termo, $tagsArray)) {
  echo 'Tag encontrada';
} else {
  echo 'Tag não encontrada';
}
```

Ou também da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$tags = 'canais,proteses,implantes';
$tagsArray = explode(',', $tags);
$termo = 'proteses';

$count = 0;
foreach ($tagsArray as $tag) {
  if ($tag == $termo) {
    $count++;
  }
}

if ($count > 0) {
  echo 'Tag encontrada';
} else {
  echo 'Tag não encontrada';
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Basta usar a função `strpos` (ou `mb_strpos` para *strings* não ASCII):

```
$palheiro = 'canais,proteses,implantes';
$agulha   = 'proteses';

$pos = strpos( $palheiro, $agulha );

// exemplo de uso:

if ($pos === false) {
   echo 'Não encontrado';
} else {
   echo 'Encontrado';
}
```

A função `strpos` retorna `false` quando a *string* não é encontrada, e caso seja encontrada, sua posição numérica.

Importante notar que se a *string* for encontrada no começo da linha, o retorno será `0`, portanto temos que usar a comparação de tipo ( `===` ou `!==` ) para diferenciar o `false` do `0`.

Outros exemplos de sintaxe:

```
$encontrado = ( strpos( $palheiro, $agulha ) !== false );

if ($encontrado) {
   echo 'Encontrado';
} else {
   echo 'Não encontrado';
}
```

```
$pos = strpos( $palheiro, $agulha );
if ( $pos !== false) echo 'encontrei!';
```

```
$pos = strpos( $palheiro, $agulha );
$encontrei = ( $pos !== false ) ? 'sim' : 'não';
echo $encontrei;
```

Teste aqui: **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/xeqqxy)**.

### Dicas:

Se sua aplicação for trabalhar com dados variáveis, é melhor se garantir e usar um formato que não dê efeitos colaterais caso você tenha palavras parecidas.

Por exemplo:

```
$palheiro = 'carro,moto,ciclomotor';
$agulha = 'moto';
// encontrado!

$palheiro = 'carro,ciclomotor';
$agulha = 'moto';
// encontrado! Opa! Peraí???
```

Isto ocorre pela palavra "ciclomotor" conter "moto".

**A solução:**

Para não precisar usar funções mais complexas, basta usar um pequeno truque:

```
$palheiro = 'carro,moto,ciclomotor';
$agulha = 'moto';
$pos = strpos( ','.$palheiro.',', ','.$agulha.',' );
// encontrado!

$palheiro = 'carro,ciclomotor';
$agulha = 'moto';
$pos = strpos( ','.$palheiro.',', ','.$agulha.',' );
// não encontrado!
```

A explicação é simples: adicionando as vírgulas nas "pontas" das duas strings, estampos procurando `,moto,`dentro de `,carro,ciclomotor,` e eliminando as ambiguidades, sem precisar apelar para funções mais complexas.

**stripos()**

Como bem lembrado pelo [@DanielOmine](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4793/), se quiser encontrar as palavras independentemente de estarem em maiúsculas ou minúsculas, você pode usar as funções *case insensitive* `stripos()` e `mb_stripos()` (várias funções do PHP tem versão com e sem o *i*, que é justamente de *insensitive*). Vale notar que estas funções internas são limitadas em relação a acentuação.

**Usando com DB**

Se estes dados estiverem vindo de uma base de dados, você pode filtrar isto diretamente no `SELECT`, temos alguns exemplos aqui no site.

Comment: Esse seu segundo código não funfou comigo!

Comment: @LeandroLobo acredito que agora ta OK, dei uma revisada